# Can I edit the remote/origin git config file?

Tags: git

What I really want to do is create aliases for common git commands that can be used by anybody using the repo... i dunno if this is possible thou. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config aren't propagated between repo.

The only way you could try and setup common configs (like common aliases) are with a **[template directory](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_template_directory)** used by the [`git init` command](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init).

> The template directory contains files and directories that will be copied to the `$GIT_DIR` after it is created.

If your team use that directory for initializing their repos, and if said directory includes a file named  '`config`', you can define common settings that way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to specify aliases in a remote repo and have them be pulled in on a clone/fetch.

The best you can do is include in your repo, a script to perform commands such as

```
git config alias.st 'status'
```

And then have anyone who needs to, run the script after cloning.